# Resizing and aligning SVG in HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't get the svg icons aligned in same height and width.

```
<img src="{{ .image1 | absURL }}" style="width: 175px; height: 50px" viewBox="0 0 75 25" alt="App Store Badge"class="mb-4">
<img src="{{ .image2 | absURL }}" style="width: 175px; height: 50px" viewBox="0 0 75 25" alt="Mac App Store Badge" class="mb-4">
```

In responsive design view it looks like this:

[image]

What am I missing please?

UPDATE:

As requested:

```
.mb-4, .my-4 {
    margin-bottom:1.5rem !important
}
```

Comment: There's no viewBox in an HTML element. You have to go into the SVG and change it. Please post the CSS for your img element (if any) and your mb4 class.

Comment: I would edit the smallest SVG to have the same dimentions as the other one. That would avoid a stretch effect on the text. There is a couple online SVG editors... The best would be to use Illustrator or equivalent software.